# Laravel receive user object

Tags: laravel

Currently I'm trying to receive the entire object (model) from the user. Right now I'm doing it like this (for example if I want to receive the email) :

```
$email = Auth::user()->email;
```

But when I do this:

```
$user = Auth::all();
```

It doesn't work obviously I'm doing something wrong. I've already searched 
in the laravel documentation but can't find it. Could someone explain this to me?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried $user = Auth::user(); ?

Comment: Oke that was fast. Thanks worked! But why user(); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$user = Auth::user();`

`Auth` is not a model! Also, I don't believe you: [Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user)

Comment: Oke thanks. Is it also possible to give that user object to for example a navbar that I've included in other views? I think it would be something like this? return compact('user'));  ??

Comment: Sure you can pass it to the view like any other variable. Since you probably don't want to do that in every controller though, I recommend you look into [View Composers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-composers)